# Chromium print dialog shows boxes instead of fonts

Tags: printing, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

When I attempt to save an email as a pdf in Chromium, using the print dialog, I get a screen full of boxes instead of font characters when the system "save as" dialog appears. The dialog does not function at all to actually save anything, but does go away when you hit the cancel key or the place on the dialog where cancel should be.  This behavior happens in any file save dialog in Chromium, such as right click save page as, or gmail save attachment as.

[image: print dialog full of boxes]

I am using Chromium Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) snap (64-bit, under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Gnome 3.36.8.

In my hunt for a fix, I have installed ttf-ancient-fonts, done a sudo apt update and updated Chromium through the Ubuntu Software GUI,  done
rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache to flush the cache, restarted Chromium, none of which made any difference.  These steps were recommended in some old threads about seeing boxes instead of characters in Chrome.  This has been happening about a week.

What would you recommend I try?

Comment: Please file a bug report on Launchpad against the chromium-browser package for this issue. It's the place for chromium snap bugs, too. Your bug report should clearly show the steps a developer should follow to reliably reproduce this issue in their testing environment.

Comment: Thanks I have reported the bug to Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem using these steps:

sudo snap remove chromium

sudo snap install chromium

New version chromium 95.0.4638.69 was installed.  I had tried to do this from the Ubuntu Software gui but the results were the same, with the same version as before, trying to reinstall from the gui interface did not have any effect on the issue.